# Access to Array value of paypal response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

with `logger.info response.inspect`

I get:

```
#<ActiveMerchant::Billing::AdaptivePaymentResponse:0x0000000599dc48 @json="{\"responseEnvelope\":{\"timestamp\":\"2012-09-24T04:34:36.888-07:00\",\"ack\":\"Failure\",\"correlationId\":\"22d02b45ed143\",\"build\":\"3692562\"},\"error\":[{\"errorId\":\"540031\",\"domain\":\"PLATFORM\",\"subdomain\":\"Application\",\"severity\":\"Error\",\"category\":\"Application\",\"message\":\"You do not have permission to issue this refund\"}]}", @response=#<Hashie::Rash error=[#<Hashie::Rash category="Application" domain="PLATFORM" error_id="540031" message="You do not have permission to issue this refund" severity="Error" subdomain="Application">] response_envelope=#<Hashie::Rash ack="Failure" build="3692562" correlation_id="22d02b45ed143" timestamp="2012-09-24T04:34:36.888-07:00">>, @xml_request="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<RefundRequest>\n  <requestEnvelope>\n    <detailLevel>ReturnAll</detailLevel>\n    <errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>\n  </requestEnvelope>\n  <actionType>REFUND</actionType>\n  <payKey>AP-2JV97573KK140871P</payKey>\n  <currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>\n  <feesPayer>EACHRECEIVER</feesPayer>\n</RefundRequest>\n", @request={"RefundRequest"=>{"requestEnvelope"=>{"detailLevel"=>"ReturnAll", "errorLanguage"=>"en_US"}, "actionType"=>"REFUND", "payKey"=>"AP-2JV97573KK140871P", "currencyCode"=>"USD", "feesPayer"=>"EACHRECEIVER"}}, @action="Refund">
```

with `response.ack` I get `"Failure"`

If I write `logger.info response.error.inspect` I get:

```
[#<Hashie::Rash category="Application" domain="PLATFORM" error_id="540031" message="You do not have permission to issue this refund" severity="Error" subdomain="Application">]
```

How can I access or get for example, `error_id` value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `response.error` is an array you have to iterate loop over it or simply do following

```
response.error[0].error_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply by this code:

```
response.error.error_id
```

For reference, look here: [rash on github](https://github.com/tcocca/rash)

In short, Rash is made to be convenient. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry but with this code I get `NoMethodError (undefined method 'error_id' for #<Array:0x000000060d8ad0>):`

Comment: Are you sure that `response.error.class` is `Hashie::Rash` then?